# How can store a multi images laravel api?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, api

I'm new in Laravel. I successfully added data to the database. expect the images.

Here is my post controller function store

```
  $post = new post();
    $post->title= $request->title;
    $post->body= $request->body;
```

for each post, I would like to add multi-images
  should I store the image path? Do I need anything else?

if you have a real example please share it with me

Comment: A common solution is to save the path to a database record, and the file somewhere in your filesystem. Preferrably the image file is not publicly accessible, so you can later control it by serving it from a Laravel controller.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you just need to save image path to database. Although it is better if you just save image name to database and assume a default path for base path. Look at this example:

```
    if ($file = $request->file('image')) {
            $post->image = $file->store('images');
        }
```

For possible name conflicts, you can use putFile method of Storage facade which automatically generate a unique ID for file name:

```
$post->image = Storage::putFile('images', $request->file('image'));
```